# Generating pdf files from docx templates from mysql database

Tags: php, html, pdf, docx

I've tried just about everything i could find so far. What i'm trying to do is save docx files in a mysql database, in which i want to replace a few strings and then convert it to  a pdf file without any saving and put that in an html object element with application/pdf in the data tag.

I've tried phpword and gears\pdf but it was mostly outdated and even when i patched them up it still required saving the files in the website directory. I've looked at phpdocx, but as far as i can tell it's not exactly what i need and i'd rather not pay that much money without being sure it is.

So my questions are:

1. Is there any way at all to do this without having to buy phpdocx?
2. If not, is phpdoxc what i need?
3. If not, are there any resources i can use to figure out how these files are made up so i can make this conversion myself without any libraries?

I hope someone can help me, i'm getting really desperate

Comment: what's the reason for the "without any saving" part?

Comment: Because i'm going to make a whole lot of files for every template and there will probably be many changes to the templates and the settings that are put into them, so it would be better to generate the files on demand and to not save them to the website directory or the database

Comment: You could still write them to a temporary file, send it via http and delete it. So the requirement of phpword and gears\pdf to save the file to disk should not rule them out. You might even be able use `php://out` as filename.

Comment: I tried doing so before and i got an error about permission to use the converting tool, i get this for all three of them (google, libreoffice and unoconv) i'm not sure what this means or if it can be resolved at all